# gunicorn: Can't connect to gunicorn.sock

Tags: django, sockets, gunicorn

I am using Django 1.8 and I want to run my application with gunicorn.

I can run it OK from the command line binding to my IP:

```
gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind xx.xx.xx.xx:8001
```

But now I want to run it via a Unix socket:

```
gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind=unix$/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
```

I get this error:

```
[2015-08-23 07:38:04 +0000] [18598] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-08-23 07:38:04 +0000] [18598] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-23 07:38:05 +0000] [18598] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-23 07:38:06 +0000] [18598] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-23 07:38:07 +0000] [18598] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-23 07:38:08 +0000] [18598] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-23 07:38:09 +0000] [18598] [ERROR] Can't connect to $/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
```

If I do `ls -al /webapps/myapp/run` I see that the socket file does exist, though it is empty:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 opuser webapps 0 Aug 23 07:22 /webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
```

How can I fix this?

I eventually want to run `gunicorn` as the user `opuser`, I've tried appending `--user opuser --group webapps` to the gunicorn command, but still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is `unix$PATH`, not `unix:PATH`? [The docs seem to suggest the latter.](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#bind)

Comment: I was getting the same message when my user had no permissions to listen the specified port (80 in my case). If this is the case and you want to run the web server under a normal user (not root), run on another port (above 1024) and redirect port 80 to this port using `iptables`.

Answer (score 11):

According to the documentation (http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/run.html), you should use: `unix:$(PATH)`, meaning your command should read:

```
gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind=unix:/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
```

Comment: Changed it - now I get the error `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/webapps/openprescribing/run/gunicorn.sock` which I guess is progress! Any idea how I can fix that? It seems odd since `opuser` is the owner of the `gunicorn.sock` file.

Comment: I guess I am not running the `gunicorn` command as `opuser`, though...? Do I need to give the current user permission to connect to `gunicorn.sock` as well?

Comment: Just for troubleshooting you can grant 777 rights to the socket and see what happens.

Comment: still the same error. I did `sudo chmod 777 /webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock`, and `ls -lash/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock` now shows `0 srwxrwxrwx  1 opuser webapps    0 Aug 23 07:22 gunicorn.sock`. But still the same `Permission denied` error.

Comment: Is there any log details other than that? Other relevant config?

Answer (score 3):

remove  `venv/run` folder and then `mkdir run` without using `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was in permissions of the `sock` file. I created new `sock` file in home directory of `non-sudo` user in `non-sudo` mode and reconfigured and it worked.